# Finding the cdf and pdf for $Z$, the standardization of $X$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with parameters $\mu\in\mathbb R$ and $\sigma^2>0$. Find the cdf and pdf for $Z$, the standardization of $X$.

What approach should I take on this? I initially thought of using the pdf of a normal distribution, but again, the question requires I find the pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standartization of $X$ is given by
$$
Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma},
$$
where $\mu=\operatorname EX$ and $\sigma^2=\operatorname{Var}X$. We have that
$$
P(Z\le z)=P\biggl(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le z\biggr)=P(X\le \sigma z+\mu)
$$
and we know that $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Hence,
$$
P(X\le \sigma z+\mu)=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\sigma z+\mu}\exp\Bigl\{ -\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr\}\mathrm dx.
$$
Using the substitution $x=\sigma t+\mu$,
$$
P(X\le \sigma z+\mu)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^z\exp\Bigl\{ -\frac{t^2}2\Bigr\}\mathrm dt.
$$
This shows that $Z\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, i.e. $Z$ has the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Now I get it. Highly appreciative